# Writing a QRegularExpression to only return the greedy last match

Tags: regex, qt

I have a input file that looks like this:

```
.SUBCKT (stuff including newline characters)
.ENDS (stuff)

.SUBCKT (stuff including newline characters)
.ENDS (stuff)

.SUBCKT (stuff including newline characters)
.ENDS (stuff)

.SUBCKT (stuff including newline characters)
.ENDS (stuff I don't want)

(What I want to get, includes a newline characters)

.END
```

So what I want to do is write a regular expression (using Qt so QRegularExpression) that will get me all the stuff that "I want to get" (between the last .ENDS and the .END without getting the "stuff I don't want". The stuff I don't want is after the last .ENDS and the first newline character after it.

My most successfull attempt at getting this has been this code:

```
QStringList toplevel;
QRegularExpression regexp_toplevel("\\.ENDS(.*?)\n(.*?)\\.END",QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption);
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator toplevel_i = regexp_toplevel.globalMatch(contents);
while (toplevel_i.hasNext()){
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = toplevel_i.next();
    toplevel << match.captured(2);
}
```

The code above returns a list of strings and the last one is what I want. But since the iteration is done java-stlye I'm not 100% percent sure that what I want will ALWAYS be the last one. Is there any way I can write the expression getting ONLY what is between the last .ENDS after the the first newline and the .END?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?ms).*^\.ENDS(?-s:.*)\n(.*)\.END
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/94GqFu/1)

**Details**:

- `(?ms)` - `m` will make `^` match a line start and `s` will make the `.` match line breaks
- `.*` - will match any 0+ chars, as many as possible (greedily), up to the *last* occurrence of...
- `^\.ENDS` - an `.ENDS` substring at the start of a line
- `(?-s:.*)` - the rest of the line (if any chars are still there)
- `\n` - a newline (may be replaced with `\\R` to match any style line break)
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars up, as many as possible, up to the last  (if you need to match up to the first `.END`, add `?` after `*`)
- `\.END` - `.END` literal substring.

Declare as

```
QRegularExpression regexp_toplevel("(?ms).*^\\.ENDS(?-s:.*)\n(.*)\\.END");
```

The value you need will be inside `match.captured(1)`.

Comment: Great!!! I'm currently learning RegExp, would you mind explaining how that expression is put together. Right from the start I see 3 capture groups, how come what I want is in the first one? Oh, and thank you very much

Comment: No, there is just 1 capturing group. `(?ms)` is an inline modifier group that sets the regex options for the entire pattern. `(?-s:.*)` is a modifier group, where the `s` (DOTALL) modifier set for the whole pattern is turned off and `.` only matches any char *but* a line break char (that is why I describe it as "the rest of the line").

Comment: Great explanation!! One more thing in the patter (?-s:.*) If I understood correctly the next group in that match will not match a newline so, the (?) is used to say you are modifying the last group modifier the -s is removing the s (DOTALL) and everything after the : is the actual regexp. Right?

Comment: [Modifier groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) (see *"Combining Non-Capture Group with Inline Modifiers"*) is just a "perk" to control parts of the pattern in a more convenient way. `(?-s:` is the part where you either enable (if you place the modifiers right after `?`) or disable (when put after `-`) a regex option.  `(?-s:.*)` means we only change what `.` matches inside this modifier group. The next `(.*)` before `\.END` [will match newlines](https://regex101.com/r/ciieTv/1).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!